# How to add a class ignore:true to all <pre tags in a post?

Tags: jquery, css

I have 100's of blog posts that have

```
<pre class='xyz'>
```

tags in them.  some reference other classes, others are just simple

```
<pre>
```

tags.  I would like to add either a query script or better a new style that would essentially have all these pre tags get another class inserted into them.  Essentially what I want the result to look like is:

```
<pre class='xyz ingore:true'/>
<pre class='ignore:true' />
```

What would be a way to achieve this?

Comment: Describe instead what behaviour you are expecting by adding this class?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do, what is the purpose of the `ignore`?

Comment: If it is being added to all `pre` tags, why not style just the `pre` tag? If its being used for other reasons, use an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, it's as simple as

```
$('pre').addClass('ignore:true');
```

Comment: "I would like to add either a query script or better a new style that would essentially have all these pre tags get another class inserted into them."

Comment: Can a class name contain a colon?

Comment: @Paulie_D ya but needs to be escaped in CSS rule: `.ignore\:true`

Comment: So `ignore-true` would be simpler...no?

Comment: @Paulie_D Sure it will that's why i guess OP would have better to describe what he is looking for

Comment: Alway sad to receive down votes.  Hard not to take personally since I put thought into my questions. The reason I did not explain more details is because "less is more".  In this case, the details would be a distraction.  The answer given is clear and shows a concise understanding of my question.  Thank you.